# Trying to copy the text of selected treeview nodes to clipboard but only getting the last node in clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel/vba to create a tree structure. Nodes have checkbox in front of them. I am using a recursive function to traverse the nodes and copy the text of selected/checked nodes. I tried to put it in variable, excel rows, arrays but I am only getting last selected node's text.

Below is the recursive function.

I am passing the root node to it. How to copy selected items?

```
Public Sub TraverseTree(objNode As Node)

    Dim objSiblingNode As Node
    Set objSiblingNode = objNode
    
   Do
        If objSiblingNode.Checked Then
        Debug.Print objSiblingNode.Text
        End If
        If Not objSiblingNode.Child Is Nothing Then
            Call TraverseTree(objSiblingNode.Child)
        End If
        Set objSiblingNode = objSiblingNode.Next
   Loop While Not objSiblingNode Is Nothing
   
End Sub
```

Tree nodes defined in VBA code

```
'Parent Nodes

TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="P1", Text:="Phone is down/blank screen"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="P2", Text:="phone is showing Configuring IP"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="P3", Text:="Phone stuck at registering"

'Child for P1

TreeView1.Nodes.Add "P1", tvwChild, "ch1", "Is the phone getting power?"

'Child for ch1

TreeView1.Nodes.Add "ch1", tvwChild, "ch1.1", "Yes"
TreeView1.Nodes.Add "ch1", tvwChild, "ch1.2", "No"

'Child for ch1.1

TreeView1.Nodes.Add "ch1.1", tvwChild, "ch1.1.1", "Do you see any buttons lit up, what are they?"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post and share (at least a picture of) your sheet keeping the three structure?

Comment: sure. i'll do it.  there is nothing in the excel sheet. everything is defined in VBA code. the parent, child etc

Comment: If nothing on the sheet, no necessary to show it to us... But, how is it built in VBA in order  the above code to return the node children?

Comment: entire tree structure is defined under Private Sub UserForm_Initialize().

Comment: In such a case you must iterate between `TreeView1.Nodes` and retrieve the text value of the one you look for, when a match exist.

Comment: iteration is happening. i have a recursive function for that and the output is also fine if i print it in MsgBox or Debug.Print. all my selected nodes are coming up. i am struggling to get selected nodes to copy to clipboard. followed the MS API as for clipboard copy but nogo. tried to put values in array nogo..

Comment: Only now I could understand your problem... I will post a piece of code which I hope will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, try the next scenario, please:

1. Declare a `Private Variable` on top of form module (in the declarations area):

```
    Private strWiew As String
```

2. Your `TraverseTree` `Sub` will become:

```
Private Sub TraverseTree(objNode As Node)
   Do
        If objNode.Checked Then
            If strWiew = "" Then
               strWiew = objNode.Text
            Else
               strWiew = strWiew & vbCrLf & vbTab & objNode.Text
            End If
        End If
        If Not objNode.Child Is Nothing Then
            Call TraverseTree(objNode.Child)
        End If
        Set objNode = objNode.Next
   Loop While Not objNode Is Nothing
End Sub
```

3. You need the function to put the resulted string in clipboard:

```
    Dim clipboard As New MSForms.DataObject

    clipboard.SetText strNode
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

4. Your `Copy` button `Click` event will become:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Dim objNode As Node
        
     Set objNode = TreeView1.Nodes("P1")
     strWiew = ""
     TraverseTree objNode
     CopyToClipboard strWiew
    End Sub
```

5. Run your application. Check the tree node you want their text to be returned and press `Copy` button. Open Notepad, Wordpad, Word (any text editor) and try `Ctrl + V`...

Comment: it worked but again just one line not all selected node to the clipboard which is the last selected node's text. i tried dataobject but not in a function.

Comment: @Munish Saxena: Of course, only one node. One at a time... In fact, can you show (in a picture, if not something editable), what you really need? Do you want a string to keep the analyzed node text and all its children after it? Eventually being expressed with a `Tab` in front? If yes, this must be built and then returned...

Comment: yes, i want to have all the checked node's text in clipboard from root to end node. i can share picture with you.. if you need i can send the excel file. how do i send it to you directly.

Comment: @Munish Saxena: Use my personal mail (in my profile). But try explaining/show how would you like the string looking, please.

Comment: @Munish Saxena: Or use a transfer site and put here the link. [here](https://easyupload.io/) is a reliable site, easy to be used...

Comment: @Munish Saxena:  In some minutes I will leave the office. I will be able to look on your workbook after I will be home...

Comment: sent you the email. if you need anything else, reply me.

Comment: I am driving now, but I checked on my mobile phone and nothing has been received... Please, check the email account spelling...

Comment: sent it to your yahoo ID and i have not received any bounce message in my inbox. did you check junk folder?

Comment: @Munish Saxena: I found it in Spam... I will look now on its code.

Comment: @Munish Saxena:. OK I could open it and run, but I cannot understand from the screenshoots what you need. Would you like to put in clipboard the checked node text **like they appear in Debug.Print**? If not, can you clarify how,  please?

Comment: @Munish Saxena:  Adapted the answer and sent back the modified workbook (as Copy of initial one...).

Comment: @Munish Saxena: Didn't you find time to test the code?